# Display the result of a calculation on different variables in an email

Tags: formula

I would like to make sure that a scenario I am proposing to my client is feasible. In SFMC we have the value of the vehicle that the prospect would like to buy as well as the residual value of his old vehicle and I would like to be able to send him an email in which I inform him of the difference to be financed and possibly of the monthly payment offer that I can propose to him ((amount to be financed / 48)+5%). Can you confirm that this is possible? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked in Marketing Cloud specifically. If MC emails can inject values from fields on the prospect, and if prospects support formula fields, this should be possible. Just create a formula field for each calculated value (the finance amount, and the monthly payment amount), and then you can use the resulting formula values in your email.